# How can i hide an application?

Tags: security, app-drawer

I want to hide some applications from other people who have access to my phone but be able to get to the application whenever I want. I don't want locking. I need it to be not seen on applications list.

Comment: Have you tried a custom launcher? This allows you to hide apps from the app drawer but it might not be exactly what you're looking for...

Comment: Newer versions of Sense also support this on HTC devices. What other info can you give us; device, Android version, rooted status etc?

Answer (score 1):

You could easily hide by using custom launchers like [Apex](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher) or [Nova](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher).

But if this is not an option, you could try apps available on Google Play like [ [CCSWE App Manager (ROOT)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ccswe.appmanager&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5jY3N3ZS5hcHBtYW5hZ2VyIl0) ] or [ [Hide App-Hide Application Icon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.apphider) ] which needs root access. *I want you to read the user feedbacks on Google Play before consider using the app because some said the icon gone forever after it was unhide.

You can also try to Disable the app from Setting -> Apps. This will hide app icon from app drawer. You can enable it again when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Lucky Patcher does that, but you will have to unhide it to use it yourself.

Home site: www.luckypatchers.com

Be careful when downloading LP :^)

PS: can be used without being root nor the machine rooted (as I do).

Comment: LP disables apps, doesn't hide. All user apps and some system apps can be disabled without root and without any third party apps.

Comment: But disabled apps are hidden to other users... unless they have the skills to use LP.

Comment: [How does freezing an app work technically?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/32285/218526)