# PM error Could not access the Package Manager

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, root-access, terminal, disable-app

I am trying to freeze an app on my phone using the solution given [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/32289/148020).

I am using the [*`Terminal Emulator`*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) app to execute the commands:

```
su
pm disable {package_name}
```

But am getting an error:

```
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
Error: Could not access the Package Manager. Is the system running?
```

This error is being generated regardless of the app I try to disable.

How do I resolve this error?

My phone is a rooted Micromax Unite 2 A106 running on Android 4.4.2.

Comment: Is the screen unlocked when you are doing this? I've only seen this error when im trying to `adb shell` but my screen is locked

Comment: I'm executing this command on the phone itself, not from a PC; so the screen is unlocked when I do this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with your version of the `su` binary. I was using ChainFire's updated binary and it didn't work. I re-rooted with Kingoroot and it's now working.